# Using System.cmd/3 in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

Probably a naive questions,

I've got this in ruby

```
system(ansible-playbook -i #{ip_address}, #{file_to_run}")
system(sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc/ansible)
```

Trying to reproduce this with variances of System.cmd/3

```
System.cmd("sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc/ansible",[],[])
```

Getting an

```
 (ErlangError) erlang error: :enoent
```

Please how do i correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each argument to the command must be given as a separate string in the list passed as second argument to `System.cmd/3`:

```
System.cmd("sudo", ["chmod", "-R", "ugo+rw", "/etc/ansible"])
```

If all the arguments are literal strings and none of them contain a space you can also use the `~w` sigil:

```
System.cmd("sudo", ~w(chmod -R ugo+rw /etc/ansible))
```

Since `System.cmd/3` has a default value for the third argument, you can omit that like I've done above.